# Field required for a nested Django Rest serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have following structure:

**Models**

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Candidate)
    candidate_test = models.ForeignKey(CandidateTest, null=True)
    # Other fields

class Candidate(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    # Other fields

class CandidateTest(models.Model):
    test_id = models.ForeignKey(Test)
    # 2 more fields with Foreign Key and null, blank both are True

class Test(models.Model):
    test_name = models.CharField()
    # 2 more fields with Foreign Key and null, blank both are True
```

**Serializers**

```
class CandidateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Candidate
        fields = ('first_name', # other fields)


class TestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = ('id', 'test_name',)


class CandidateTestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    test_id = TestSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = CandidateTest
        fields = ('id', 'test_id')


class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = CandidateSerializer()
    candidate_test = CandidateTestSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'candidate_test')
```

Now when I submit (POST) form using Django Rest Framework's browsable API I get following error:

```
'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Following is the stacktrace:

```
Error during template rendering

In template /srv/www/safe/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages    /rest_framework/templates/rest_framework/horizontal/fieldset.html, error at line 11
'list' object has no attribute 'get'
1   {% load rest_framework %}
2   <fieldset>
3     {% if field.label %}
4       <div class="form-group" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5">
5         <legend class="control-label col-sm-2 {% if style.hide_label %}sr-only{% endif %}" style="border-bottom: 0">
6           {{ field.label }}
7         </legend>
8       </div>
9     {% endif %}
10  
11  

  {% for nested_field in field %}



12      {% if not nested_field.read_only %}
13        {% render_field nested_field style=style %}
14      {% endif %}
15    {% endfor %}
16  </fieldset>
17  
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

/srv/www/safe/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response

                                response = response.render()

     ...
▶ Local vars
/srv/www/safe/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py in render

                            self.content = self.rendered_content

     ...
▶ Local vars
/srv/www/safe/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/response.py in rendered_content

                        ret = renderer.render(self.data, media_type, context)

     ...
▶ Local vars
/srv/www/safe/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py in render

                        context = self.get_context(data, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)

     ...
▶ Local vars
/srv/www/safe/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py in get_context

                            'post_form': self.get_rendered_html_form(data, view, 'POST', request),

     ...
▶ Local vars
/srv/www/safe/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py in get_rendered_html_form

                                    [('template', 'rest_framework/api_form.html')]

     ...
▶ Local vars
/srv/www/safe/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py in render

                        return template.render(context)

     ...
▶ Local vars
/srv/www/safe/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py in render

                        return self.template.render(context)

     ...
▶ Local vars
/srv/www/safe/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py in render

                                    return self._render(context)

     ...
▶ Local vars
/srv/www/safe/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py in _render

                        return self.nodelist.render(context)

     ...
▶ Local vars
/srv/www/safe/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py in render

                                bit = self.render_node(node, context)

     ...
▶ Local vars
/srv/www/safe/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py in render_node

                            return node.render(context)

     ...
▶ Local vars
/srv/www/safe/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py in render

                                            nodelist.append(node.render(context))

     ...
▶ Local vars
/srv/www/safe/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py in render

                                return nodelist.render(context)

     ...
▶ Local vars
/srv/www/safe/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py in render

                                bit = self.render_node(node, context)

     ...
▶ Local vars
/srv/www/safe/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py in render_node

                            return node.render(context)

     ...
▶ Local vars
/srv/www/safe/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py in render

                                    return func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)

     ...
▶ Local vars
/srv/www/safe/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/templatetags/rest_framework.py in render_field

                    return renderer.render_field(field, style)

     ...
▶ Local vars
/srv/www/safe/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py in render_field

                        return template.render(context)

     ...
▶ Local vars
/srv/www/safe/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py in render

                        return self.template.render(context)

     ...
▶ Local vars
/srv/www/safe/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py in render

                                    return self._render(context)

     ...
▶ Local vars
/srv/www/safe/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py in _render

                        return self.nodelist.render(context)

     ...
▶ Local vars
/srv/www/safe/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py in render

                                bit = self.render_node(node, context)

     ...
▶ Local vars
/srv/www/safe/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py in render_node

                            return node.render(context)

     ...
▶ Local vars
/srv/www/safe/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py in render

                                            nodelist.append(node.render(context))

     ...
▶ Local vars
/srv/www/safe/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py in render

                                return nodelist.render(context)

     ...
▶ Local vars
/srv/www/safe/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py in render

                                bit = self.render_node(node, context)

     ...
▶ Local vars
/srv/www/safe/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py in render_node

                            return node.render(context)

     ...
▶ Local vars
/srv/www/safe/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py in render

                                    return func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)

     ...
▶ Local vars
/srv/www/safe/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/templatetags/rest_framework.py in render_field

                    return renderer.render_field(field, style)

     ...
▶ Local vars
/srv/www/safe/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py in render_field

                        return template.render(context)

     ...
▶ Local vars
/srv/www/safe/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py in render

                        return self.template.render(context)

     ...
▶ Local vars
/srv/www/safe/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py in render

                                    return self._render(context)

     ...
▶ Local vars
/srv/www/safe/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py in _render

                        return self.nodelist.render(context)

     ...
▶ Local vars
/srv/www/safe/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py in render

                                bit = self.render_node(node, context)

     ...
▶ Local vars
/srv/www/safe/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py in render_node

                            return node.render(context)

     ...
▶ Local vars
/srv/www/safe/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py in render

                                values = list(values)

     ...
▶ Local vars
/srv/www/safe/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/utils/serializer_helpers.py in __iter__

                            yield self[field.field_name]

     ...
▶ Local vars
/srv/www/safe/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/utils/serializer_helpers.py in __getitem__

                        error = self.errors.get(key) if self.errors else None

     ...
▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
field   

IntegerField(label='ID', read_only=True)

self    

<NestedBoundField value={} errors=[u'This field is required.']>

key     

'id'

value   

None
```

Also note that using requests its working fine...

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in rest framework, and it is still not fixed:
https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/4073

To fix it, the only way i figured out so far is this:

in your class inherited from `ModelSerializer` or `Serializer`, override `__getitem__` method:

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    field = self.fields[key]
    value = self.data.get(key)
    error = self.errors.get(key) if hasattr(self, '_errors') else None
    if isinstance(field, serializers.Serializer):
        return NestedBoundField(field, value, field.data)
    return BoundField(field, value, error)
```

It would pass down field.data instead of error, might cause some further issues, but so far it's better than passing down error as list (nested serializer expects error tree to be entirely filled, but it receives parent error message instead)

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your `CustomerSerializer` serializer:

```
candidate_test = CustomerSerializer()
```

should likely be:

```
candidate_test = CandidateTestSerializer()
```

Comment: thanks but it was during typing it in here, it's not the actual problem.